# Is it possible to use multiple parsers and preserve line numbers?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, context-free-grammar, peg

I asked a semi-related question about a month ago:
[Is parsing in multiple passes common for PEG grammars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739098/is-parsing-in-multiple-passes-common-for-peg-grammars) I was trying to figure out if it's an OK idea to write several grammars in order to progressively parse the input of some text in passes. For my pet project, a music programming language (MPL) parser, I've written 3 separate grammars:

1. Take the entire contents of source file and strip out the comments.
2. Take the source file (comments removed) and separate it by instrument. This results in pairs of instrument name/definition and the "music code" to be "played" by said instrument.
3. Actually parse music code (one string of text per instrument) and return a parse tree of music "events" for each instrument.

The one person who answered my previous question indicated that this is a sound approach, and that it's reasonable to have a comment-removal pass if your parser generator tool doesn't have a way to do this automatically/simply. The only potential reason he could see for unifying the grammars would be if there were a performance requirement, but there is none in my case.

Thinking about this more, though, I'm wondering about the ramifications on exception handling. Ideally, when my parser throws an exception, I would like for it to identify the correct line number in the *original source file* and display an error message identifying the parse error. My parser generating tool of choice, [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) has nice error messages that identify the line and column numbers, like this:

```
Parse error at line 1, column 1:
bbaaaab
^
Expected:
"ab"
```

The problem is that these errors are thrown on a per-pass basis. If I have an initial grammar that I'm using to strip out the comments from the source file, then the original line numbers are not preserved, going onto the next pass. I really hope this is not the case, but it seems to me that the only way to preserve the correct line numbers would be to unify everything into a single, very complicated grammar. Is there a way around this? Is there some pattern for writing multiple, successive grammars and still preserving the line numbers from the original input?

Comment: Hack proposal: how about, in step 1, instead of stripping out the bytes that make up the comments, you replace those bytes with white-space of the same size. That should keep line numbers and positions unchanged.

Comment: That's an interesting idea... I'm not sure how I would preserve the newlines, though. My "long comment" definition would need to have some way of counting the lines, and then be replaced by the right number of newlines to preserve the line count. But that just might work, if there is no other alternative...

Comment: What's a point of stripping the comments? Just ignore them as white spaces.

Comment: Whoa... I can't believe that never occurred to me. I think I've even read that at some point while learning about writing a CFG. If you can elaborate on that as an answer, I'll accept it.